# How to access to items in dictionaries within a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a column in a dataframe and each row is a list which is a collection of many dictionaries with the same keys. I want to get all the items from a same key inside the dictionaries.

I have this list:

```py
s = [{'category': 'Public',
      'name': 'Newspaper',
      'person': 'A'},

     {'category': 'Music',
      'name': 'Andre',
      'person': 'B'},

     {'category': 'Music',
      'name': 'Indian',
      'person': 'A'},

     {'category': 'Artist',
      'name': 'Rihe',
      'person': 'D'},

     {'category': 'Interest',
      'name': 'Sport',
      'person': 'B'}]
```

I've tried using a loop and itemgetter but it takes a lot of time due to the large data. I'm looking for a more efficient way to do it.

```py
from operator import itemgetter 
   category = []
   name_page = []
   getter_category = itemgetter('category')
   getter_name = itemgetter('name')     
   for element  in s:        
      name_page.append(getter_name(element))
      category.append(getter_category(element))
```

I want something more efficient like:

```py
s['category'] = ['Public','Music','Music','Artist','Interest']
s['name'] = ['Newspaper','Andre','Indian','Rihe','Sport']
s['person'] = ['A','B','A','D','B']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `defaultdict` from `collections`

```
from collections import defaultdict
o = defaultdict(list)
for ss in s:
    for k, v in ss.items():
        o[k] += [v]

print(dict(o))
Out[7]:
{'category': ['Public', 'Music', 'Music', 'Artist', 'Interest'],
 'name': ['Newspaper', 'Andre', 'Indian', 'Rihe', 'Sport'],
 'person': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'B']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to use dictionaries. I've found the easiest way and it's using dataframes.

```
s = pd.DataFrame(s)

-------------------------
|category  | name  | person|
-------------------------
|Public    | Music | Music |
---------------------------
|Newspaper | Andre | Indian|
----------------------------

s['category'].to_list()    =    ['Public','Music','Music','Artist','Interest']
```